# HP business desktops fail non-HP hard drives in BIOS disk test. True?

Tags: hard-drive, hp-desktop-computer

Since I have NOT needed to be out on the bleeding edge, of late I have been buying factory refurbished or trusted re-builder refurbeded business desktops. For the ones with Windows, they often don't have all the useless consumer grade eye-candy and hand-holding software. They may even have systems management clients!
Anyway, the last 4 machines I've built out have all had 40 GiB hard drives. In my newest box, which is a barebones machine, the HD is the 40 GiB, but was unformatted. {It *was* barebones}
When the format for Win7 Ultimate failed overnight, I ran my standard diagnostics tools. They all said the drive was good. Another nuke and boot to go with the OS again. Failed again. This time, I went into the Bios disk test routine. It said that my otherwise good HD was not.
One of my tech resources said that it was common knowledge that a Non-HP disk tested with the Bios test would always fail. I am interested in this because I am going to be upgrading the boot drives on several of these machines....

Has anyone had any experience with this?

Comment: I'd never had a problem swapping out larger HD's for smaller ones, Seagate, WD, Hitachi, IBM... all the majors. I use Acronis to backup and migrate disk to disk. The problem happened when I was working on the bare metal with my Win7 Ultimate NFR I got at the release shindig last fall... And with no OS, nothing to swap.

Comment: I never had a problem like this with desktops, HP or otherwise. For **servers** however there have been lock downs. Mostly by Dell as far as I remember, but I never did much with HP servers.

Answer (score 0):

I have a HP business desktop at home, and I changed all my harddrives with absolutely no problems. True, I never run a disk test from BIOS, but they are working perfectly. Anyway, the original HDD was also a Hitachi, not HP. Now I have a Western Digital and a Samsung.

This is a HP DX2300 desktop, bought new about 3 years ago. I've put in it additional RAM and video card and TV tuner and wireless (over PCI) card ... I had absolutely no problem with any additional non-HP hardware.